# Handling AJAX requests if a session has expired

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my app (ASP.NET MVC 3 RAZOR), when a session expires and the user tries to access something, it redirects them to the login page to re-login.

This is fine, but when calling from ajax requests (e.g. if the user has left their screen for a while with no activity), it will load the login form in the ajax request... Which is not what I want to happen.

What is the best way of dealing with this? Ideally I'd like to show a modal if the session has expired so the user can't access other areas. So even if they leave the screen some jQuery will have checked the session and then applied a modal saying 'Session Expired'

How would I do this?

e.g.

```
if(SESSION HAS EXPIRED) { showModal(); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two separate addressable issues here, so I will discuss them each separately.

**Login returned as AJAX result**:
Rather than just return the login screen, return a message indicating that the session has expired. If your AJAX receives such a message, it knows the user needs to log back in. At this point, you can do something like

```
window.location = loginpageurlhere;
```

Alternately, you can check your AJAX response to see if it is an expected response or if it is the login page. If it is the login page, use the above suggestion.

**Display dialog if user is inactive for too long**:
For this, you need to know how long the user is inactive. You can do this in a couple different ways, one of which is as follows:

- When the page loads, initialize a variable to use as a countdown.
- Set a timer that will decrement the counter every time it runs out of time, and then restart.
- If the counter ever hits zero, display the dialog and have the user log back in.
- Every time a valid activity occurs (AJAX post or whatever else you may have), reset the counter.

You could use either, of these methods, although if you are concerned about protecting data at an unattended machine, the second method would be best, since you can block the screen and only display the dialog, and it will happen while the user is away, whereas the first method can't do anything until a user actually attempts to perform an action on your page.

Comment: Thanks ;) I'm gonna do the countdown.

Comment: I like the statusCode parameter for handling this (per Darin), but it's really just a matter of preference. Checking the successfully returned data for some sort of "no longer authenticated" flag or string will work just as well, really. I wouldn't rely on the countdown; it's just a fake session and easily spoofed. You need to handle the real server session as well. The countdown could be fine for a "you have gone idle" dialog though.

Comment: @Greg Agreed. The session needs to be tracked server side. It seems the OP is already doing that, but in addition just wants a way to notify the user when the session expires, so the spoof shouldn't be an issue since the server doesn't know whether the user thinks it is still authenticated.

Comment: the countdown method doesn't work as expected if the user opens the same page in a new tab and logs out there.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a global error handler in jQuery which will be called every time an error is caught by jQuery ajax. If a session times out then a 401 error is thrown. This can be caught and the user redirected to the login page.

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 401) {
        window.location.replace("/login");
    }
});
```

The global error handler should always be added to the document object.

Comment: This is the best solution so far

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) which illustrates a nice technique allowing you to have the server return 401 status code in this case which could be captured on the client side and respective actions taken (showing a modal to the user).

Comment: While this is nice I'd prefer to detect if the session has expired and then do something globally so say the user had left their screen the JS could fire a redirect to another page or show the modal.

Comment: @Cameron, what prevents you from doing so? You could have a global complete AJAX handler for your entire application, so any 401 status code returned by the server by any of your AJAX calls will be centralized in a single function which will handle them. In this function if you detect 401 status code you could do whatever you want: redirect, show a modal, ...

Comment: Agreed; and having the statusCode handler means you can anticipate and deal with other server states as well. For example, perhaps your application has user roles--issue a 403 for requests the user doesn't have sufficient permissions for.