# JQuery ajax call breaks when page sits open for a long time

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

First off, I'm new to javascript and JQuery, so I hope this isn't a newbie question.

The project I'm working on is an MVC3 application.  I am making an AJAX call as follows and everything works, normally.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'blah',
  data: {data1: '', data2: ''},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(val){

  },
  error: function(message){
    alert("Error!");
  }
```

My problem is this, if the screen sits open for a long period of time, with no user interaction, my ajax call does not get fired and I get an error.  I have put a break point in my C# code on the controller function that gets called and never gets hit after the long period of inactivity.

Again to reiterate, it works normally but only breaks after a long period of inactivity (30+ minutes).  This is an edge case, but still a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: To update, the alert("Error!") is thrown, so I know that the function is being called.

Comment: Could it be due to a session timeout? Have you debugged the application and request lifecycle events?

Comment: This is very likely.. is there a good javascript/jquery way check if the page has timed out?

Comment: @user959729   Plenty of answers to that on here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729011/1880925)

Comment: The link you gave was perfect. This is what I was looking for.  Thanks @ROYFinley

Comment: If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave your session for more than 30 minutes, is very probable you have your session timed out. You can do two things (and I guess there are a lot more things to do!)

1. You can modify your session time out in your web.config file:

   > < sessionState 
   >   ........
   >   timeout="minutes"................../>

**NOTE:** If you give too much time in this configuration, and you have too many visits, you might have memory problems on your web server.

1. You can decorate your action in your controler with this attribute:

> [AllowAnonymous]
>   
>   **NOTE:** AllowAnonymousAttribute works with MVC 4 or later versions. If you want to implement in previous version. Finally this might have security issues to your application.

I hope this can help!